# phpmyadmin not opening and showing "The page isn't working HTTP ERROR 500"

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

[image]

Below is my `apache2 php.ini` log file line which shows Fatal error.

> [Thu Jan 23 11:21:04.634143 2020] [php7:error] [pid 9929] [client
>   ::1:56044] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes
>   exhausted (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in
>   /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php on line 144

I have tried to solve this issue by increasing memory_limit by 4gb but still i am getting this error and it won't open the PHPMYADMIN.

Also when i am running any Project code then it runs properly if any file does not containg `exit()` OR `die()`. If i wrote `exit()` OR `die()` in any file then the project stops working.

I don't understand what is the issue.

Comment: check phpinfo() if the increased memory has taken effect? maybe you're editing wrong file

Comment: @RakeshShewale Yes I have checked in phpinfo() and it has taken the effect and shows me gb memory_limit in it.

Comment: you must try changing the memory limit for phpmyadmin to -1. take a look here: https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_MemoryLimit

Comment: I have change memory_limit from 4gb to -1 and it runs now correctly. Thanks @RakeshShewale

Comment: @Yogendrasinh you shouldn't allow PHP to consume unlimited memory. Set a reasonable amount like in vishal's first part of his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your php.ini in apache config
check below

```
   memory_limit = 256M
   upload_max_size = 64M
   post_max_size = 64M
   upload_max_filesize = 64M
   max_execution_time = 300
   max_input_time = 1000
```

or

you can set memory_limit = -1 to resolve this issues.

Comment: Setting no upper limit in available memory to PHP is no good idea...

Answer (score 0):

If not fixed by the above then very likely to be missing json support on Cent OS 8

```
yum install php-json
```

I spent ages trying to figure out why following everyone's instructions on how to install phpmyadmin which resulted "in this page isn't working" hopefully this will save someone's time!

Comment: Your provided answer might fix someone's problem with setting up phpMyAdmin but is completely unrelated to the OPs issue with memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

For me I just started apache and then refresh phpmyadmin tab boob it works